# How can update list entities like field in another entity?(remove all old and save all new values)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entity with MAnyToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PP_CONFIG")
public class PricePlanConfig {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
    @Getter @Setter private String Name;
    @Getter @Setter private String wfaId;
    @Getter @Setter private Integer status;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Getter @Setter private List<PricePlanCrm> ppCrm;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PP_CRM")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"id", "ppConfig"})
public class PricePlanCrm {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
    @Getter @Setter private String rkId;
    @Getter @Setter private String name;
    @Getter @Setter private String priceplantype;
    @Getter @Setter private String enabled;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ppCrm")
    @Getter @Setter private List<PricePlanConfig> ppConfig;
```

I want update

```
@Getter @Setter private List<PricePlanCrm> ppCrm;
```

And i do it

```
public void updatePricePlainsToCurrentPricePlaneConfig(){
        List<PricePlanCrm> pricePlansClear = getPricePlansClear();
        currentPricePlanConfig.setPpCrm(pricePlansClear);
        PricePlanCrmDaoImpl.me().merge(currentPricePlanConfig);
    }
```

in `pricePlansClear`  I have 3 new values and in `currentPricePlanConfig.setPpCrm()` I have 7 old values. Ifter update/merge I want 3 new values in my `currentPricePlanConfig`. But not happend. I do not have errors but new values not set to `currentPricePlanConfig`.

If I add new value to current - it added.
But I want remove all old values and set all new values.